# Not able to catch c# web api exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im having issues catching an Exception

I have the following method in my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public void Register(SampleModel request)
{
    //Some code
}
```

In Postman if I send my sample request in xml or json it automagically maps to my POCO SampleModel, I use encapsulation to do some data validation on the fields passed, for example if one of the properties passed is null I throw an argument null exception.

**My question is: How can I catch that exception in my controller and return the exception message back to the client/user?**

A scenario I've thought of would be to have a copy of my model with no argument requirement checking and then in my controller pass the no argument checking model to the argument checking model in a try catch block, but that doesn't seem efficient.

Heres an example of one of the properties in my model

```
private string _client;
public string Client
{
    get { return _client; }
    set 
    { 
        if(string.isNullOrEmpty(value) throw new ArgumentNullException(); 
        _client = value;
    }   
}
```

I'm using C# 5.0

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Please expand your question by including a [mcve].  In particular show us how you're doing your validation.

Comment: @Amy: He's asking how to catch exceptions thrown during model binding.

Comment: @SLaks that's possible, but i'm not sure.  he says "... use encapsulation to do some data validation...if one of the properties passed is null I throw an argument null exception."   his usage of "I throw" sounds to me like he's doing his validation incorrectly.

Comment: I included one of the properties that exist in my model, is this validation incorrect? I'm not sure of any other way.

Comment: No, that's incorrect.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @Amy Thank you Amy. I will read the document. Glad I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch it in your controller action with with simple try catch and return and HttpResponseMessage with Status 500 - Http Status Code Internal Server Error and your message as content.

If everything fine, then return HttpResponseMessage with Status 200.

Still this way of validation is incorrect and in case of incorrect input 4xx status codes are better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WebApi Action that returns `void` (your example) or a model, you can return an error response by throwing an `HttpResponseException`.  The Framework includes appropriate handling for a `HttpResponseException`.  Something like:

For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Register(SampleModel request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(
             HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
             "Missing or invalid SampleModel");
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
    ...
}
```